# Cyclic notation for residue classes mod $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, cyclic-groups

I am reading an example from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition.

I am wondering why the authors do not use the bar notation for the element of residue classes.
For example, why do they write $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\langle~1~\rangle$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\langle~\bar{1}~\rangle$?

The reason why I am confused is that they once use the bar notation when they introduce groups $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and suddenly switche to this notation. Is it a common practice not to use the bar when denoting an element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, or is there any other reason for why they do not use the bar notation here?

[image]

Comment: It's very common practice. Also, it is aligned with defining  $n:=\overbrace{1+\dots+1}^n$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Try typsetting a paper or 200-page thesis with bars everywhere.  You'll come around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see the author is now discussing the subgroups of $G=Z_n$, not $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, that's why different notation is used.
In the book, the author denotes $Z_n=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ and $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}=\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\dots,\overline{n-1}\}$

Comment: I try to avoid using   ${\mathbb Z}_n$ because it causes so much confusion, but if I do use it then I define it to be equal to ${\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$. Denoting $\bar{1}$ by $1$ is just a convenient abuse of notation.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ya actually both notation are the same in the sense that the two groups stated are isomorphic, and denoting $\bar{1}$ by $1$ is simpler.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Do you think calling the multiplicative identity in a (unitary) ring $1$ is _always_ an "abuse of notation", or is that only when the ring happens to be a quotient of $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think perhaps that abuse of notation was not exactly what I meant. I meant a simplification of notation to be used when there is no danger of confusion. So I would denote the multiplicative identity in a ring $R$ by $1_R$, but say we will usually just write $1$. Unfortunately many students do succeed in getting confused!

Comment: @AlanWang I thought that even if it was a convention to denote the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ simply by $\{0, 1, ldots, n-1\}$, the authors would say so before using the convention. And it was actually the case. They mention it on page 10. Thank you.